# $f(x)$ polynomial over field without repeated roots. Projective closure of $y^2=f(x)$ over field $k$ possibly non-singular curve for $\deg(f)\geq 4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field s.t. $f(x)$ degree $n\geq 3$ polynomial does not have repeated roots in algebraic closure. Consider $F(x,y)=y^2-f(x)$. Then $\operatorname{Spec}(k[x,y]/F)\subset P^2_k=\operatorname{Proj}(k[x_0,x_1,x_2])$ as scheme. WLOG, we can assume $x=\frac{x_1}{x_0},y=\frac{x_2}{x_0}$. Then homogenization gives $G(x_0,x_1,x_2)=x_0^{n-2}x_2^2-x_0^nf(\frac{x_1}{x_0})\in k[x_0,x_1,x_2]$.

Now one can use Jacobian criterion to tell whether $(0,0,1)$ point is singular or not. It is not singular when $n=3$. However, it will become singular once $n\geq 4$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ The book says "The one dimensional regular scheme without singular point is called hyperelliptic curve for $n\geq 5$ and for $n=4$, such an elliptic curve is actually an elliptic curve." Does this contradict with regularity checking by Jacobian criterion above? Above concludes the point at $(0,0,1)$ is always singular once $n\geq 4$.

Ref. Ueno, Algebraic Geometry 3, Chpt 7, Sec 2, Example 7.33

Comment: He is talking about the one dimensional regular scheme without singular points associated to the projective closure of the affine equation. Both the hyperelliptic curves and the elliptic curves are always nonsingular.

Comment: @GunnarSveinsson So he is not referring to specific type of $y^2=f(x)$ equations then?

Comment: To get a hyperelliptic curve, take an affine equation as above, then take projective closure. This will have singular points for $n \geq 4$. Now you can desingularize it in a certain way (take a smooth projective curve with the same function field) and this is what is referred to as the hyperelliptic curve or elliptic curve.

Comment: I changed deg to \deg so that you see $\deg(f)$ rather than $deg(f).$ The effect is NOT only to prevent italicization, but also to get context-dependent spacing, so that for example in $\deg f$ you see more space to the right of $\deg$ than you do in $\deg(f)$, and you see things like $3\deg(f)$ instead of $3\text{deg}(f).$ Similarly I wrote \operatorname{Spec}. $\qquad$